# Use ESlint with expressjs

Tags: javascript, express, eslint

I would like to use ESlint with express together and keep the `no-unused-vars` rule on.

Now when I have ESlint on I get the following:

[image]

I would like to turn the `no-unused-vars` rule off only for express functions. Is this possible?

Comment: You can add the rule at the top of your file

Comment: Why not just omitting req, res and next if you don't actually use them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ESLint documentation, `no-unused-var` supports ignore patterns:

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern